# Serialization writeObject failed internally

Tags: java, serialization, corba, jdk1.4, iiop

I have java (version 4, I know it is outdated) thread, which contacts other application, running on corba server. So while making corba call it throwing below exception.

```
[100106915, Serializable writeObject method failed internally, com.sun.corba.se.internal.io.IIOPOutputStream.throwExceptionType(Native Method)
com.sun.corba.se.internal.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:142)
com.sun.corba.se.internal.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:136)
com.sun.corba.se.internal.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:116)
org.jacorb.util.ValueHandler.writeValue(ValueHandler.java:32)
org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream.write_value_internal(CDROutputStream.java:2879)
org.jacorb.orb.CDROutputStream.write_value(CDROutputStream.java:2521)
```

What can be the issue? I am suspecting that issue is with JDK, but This issue is there on live server so I can't actually change the JDK and test it.

How can I even analyse this issue?

Please let me know, If you need any other information.

Comment: It looks like your stream contains objects that are nor serializable.

Comment: I have verified it..It is implementing serializable

Comment: Did you verify that all the elements in object graph are serializable ? If they are not, they need to be marked transient.

Comment: I have verified that also....They are serializable..It is very old code..It used to work fine...today suddenly i saw this exception in my logs and functionality is not working fine :(

Comment: what are the other things I should check ?

Comment: What JacORB version are you using? Can you try upgrading that ?